# FCR calculations in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to work the (First Contact Resolution) FCR in excel however so success.

Does anyone know an automated formula used in excel?

We have been trying to use formulas to check how many times a customer with the same customer ID calls us in 7 days.

Comment: Could you post some sample data? It'd be of great use.

Comment: Would `COUNTIF` function work?

Comment: @Mark Fitzgerald - Yes I tried using the Countif but if for example a customer called on 22/03 and then he calls again within 7 days period that should return "0" otherwise "1" but if he calls in on 01/04 it should count as 1 as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your requirement

```
        ID  Date    Calls Count in last 7 days from today
        1   13-Mar-17   2
        2   14-Mar-17   0
        5   15-Mar-17   1
        1   16-Mar-17   2
        3   17-Mar-17   1
        5   18-Mar-17   1
        7   19-Mar-17   1
        9   20-Mar-17   1
        1   21-Mar-17   2
        13  22-Mar-17   1
        2   23-Mar-17   0
        17  24-Mar-17   0
        5   25-Mar-17   1
        21  26-Mar-17   0
```

Putting ID in Column A and Dates in Column B and records starts from row 2
put this formula in Cell "C2":

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,">="&TODAY()-6,B:B,"<="&TODAY())
```

and drag it all way down to see the number of calls

or put this formula if you want to calculate last 7 days from the date in sheet:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,">="&B2-6,B:B,"<="&B2)
```

Please let me know if you meant something else as I tried my best to assume the senario.

Comment: @S K - I tried applying this to my date however it is not exactly what we need.

Comment: @AnnaliseAzzopardi could you please explain a little more like in which column what data is there and you need only "0" or "1" as Boolean ?

Comment: I would like to thank you for your information it worked :) thanks a lot

Comment: @AnnaliseAzzopardi  thanks for your confirmation. I humbly request you to accept the answer as it worked, I would be really thankful.